# No marker on line titles

Tags: plot, key, google-maps-markers, legend

I want to remove the markers (dots) after every keys as shown in the figure. I just need the title.  Also please suggest me simple way to move individual title near to the curves. I am using coordinate to move around each labels.

```
plot "x" using 1:2 lp title "A" at 1,1
```

Thank you very much.